# TinyMCE wrong element path with multiple editors

Tags: php, mysql, tinymce-4

I am building some sort of blogging platform and I use TinyMCE as editor for that platform, the problem is that I have multiple editors on the same page and they work fine but the element_paths show up under the wrong editor. [image: Here you can see what I mean]

As you can see the paths under the editors aren't working correctly: text in top editor is strong and the element path tells me it is em which is only correct for the bottom editor, so these element paths are swapped. I think it might have to do something with loading in content dynamically with PHP so [here](http://hastebin.com/egapaxutum.xml) is my page code. Thanks in advance, I hope we can figure it out.